# Writing words in a list and their positions to a file

Tags: python, list, file

I have been assigned a task at school (I will copy paste the details as it will explain it better than I can)

> Develop a program that identifies individual words in a sentence, stores these in a list and replaces each word in the original sentence with the position of that word in the list.

For example, the sentence

```
ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY
```

Contains the words ASK, NOT, WHAT, YOUR, COUNTRY, CAN, DO, FOR, YOU
The sentence can be recreated from the positions of these words in this list using the sequence

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,3,9,6,7,8,4,5
```

Save the list of words and the positions of these words in the sentence as separate files or as a single file.

> Analyse the requirements for this system and design, develop, test and evaluate a program to:
>
> - identify the individual words in a sentence and store them in a list
> - create a list of positions for words in that list
> - save these lists as a single file or as separate files.

_

So far I have been able to write the words to a file but not the numbers -I am only getting the number 1- Any help is very welcome:)

```
 words=['ASK','NOT','WHAT','YOUR','COUNTRY','CAN','DO','FOR','YOU','ASK','WHAT','YOU','CAN','DO','FOR','YOUR','COUNTRY'] 
    word_raw = ['ASK','NOT','WHAT','YOUR','COUNTRY','CAN','DO','FOR','YOU']
    numbers = ['']
    if 'ASK' in words:
        numbers.append('0')
        numbers.append('9')
    
    if 'NOT' in words:
        numbers.append('1')
    
    if 'WHAT' in words:
        numbers.append('2')
        numbers.append('10')
        
    if 'YOUR' in words:
        numbers.append('3')
        numbers.append('15')
    
    if 'COUNTRY' in words:
        numbers.append('4')
        numbers.append('16')
    
    if 'CAN' in words:
        numbers.append('5')
        numbers.append('12')
    
    if 'DO' in words:
        numbers.append('6')
        numbers.append('13')
    
    if 'FOR' in words:
        numbers.append('7')
        numbers.append('15')
    if 'YOU' in words:
        numbers.append('8')
        numbers.append('11')
        
        print (numbers)
    for x in range(len(words)):
        MyFile = open('Task2File.txt', 'w')   
        with open("Task2File.txt", mode="w",encoding="utf-8") as my_file:
              for words in word_raw:
                   my_file.write(words+"\n")                                                             
    for x in range(len(numbers)):
        MyFile = open('Task2FileNumbers.txt', 'w')   
        with open("Task2FileNumbers.txt", mode="w",encoding="utf-8") as my_file:
              for numbers in numbers:
                   my_file.write(numbers+"\n")
                   print (numbers)
```

Comment: It looks like there's an issue with your for loop, specifically `for numbers in numbers`. You probably want something more like `for number in numbers` (and to change subsequent references to use `number`). Also, there's no need to assign the `MyFile` value as you're doing.

Comment: `for word in words:  print(words.index(word))` ? maybe its not really clear

Comment: @JoranBeasley this wouldn't really work, because the `.index()` method will return the left-most index of the word, so if there is more than one word in sentence/list, it will always return exact the same index for both occurences. There is an option to pass extra __start__ argument to `.index(sub[, start[, end]])` method, but that's a different story.

Comment: @Nf4r I think thats what he wants based on his output numbers (see repeated 3's)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the things dictionaries are best at.

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
words = sentence.split()
word_num = 1
word_dict = {}
output = []
for word in words:
    if word not in word_dict:
        word_dict[word] = word_num
        word_num += 1
    output.append(word_dict[word])
print(output)
```

It's probably easiest to write the lists as a single file to make sure they are in the same order.

```
with open('output.txt', 'w+') as f:
     f.writelines(' '.join([key, str(value), '\n']) 
                  for key, value in sorted(word_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]))
```

Comment: So with this, how would I then re-write the sentence and numbers in a file?

Answer (score 0):

```
sentence = "ASK NOT WHAT YOUR COUNTRY CAN DO FOR YOU ASK WHAT YOU CAN DO FOR YOUR COUNTRY"
words = sentence.split()
d = {w: words.index(w) + 1 for w in set(words)}
output = [d[word] for word in words]
print(output)
```